Bridge mode with Huawei AR611 router
My provider provides me with 1 IPv4 /28 block and 1 IPv6 /56 block, through a router they own and to which I do not have access.
If I use the cable that comes from my provider's router, I can use any IP, whether IPv4 or IPv6.
However, now I need to connect this cable that comes out of the router owned by the provider, to my AR611 Huawei router, in which I have access to the web-based panel and can also enter configuration by uploading .cnf files (from within the web -based, as I don't have access to console mode).
In the web-based interface, I couldn't find anything that would help me configure this device as a bridge (that is, being able to use any IP from the blocks connecting to LAN ports 0-3).
Does anyone know how I can get it?
